# Slow loop using data.table and lapply in R

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a function `fnEp_` that takes a `data.table` column, a `data.table` and a `logical` type. I am trying to make the function iterate over each element of `eltIndexEnriched$Max` (see  below). It works but it is very slow. I wonder if there is a better way to iterate or perhaps a setting to make it faster.

Here I am creating a column `EP_1` in the `data.table` from  a function called `fnEP_` using `lapply`:

```
eltIndexEnriched <- eltIndexEnriched[, EP_1 := 
                  lapply(Max, fnEp_, dt = eltIndexEnriched, Indemn_Bool = TRUE)]

fnEp_ <- function(Att_, dt, Indemn_Bool) {
    if (Indemn_Bool == TRUE) { 
        retval <- (1 - exp(-1 * sum(dt$Rate * (ifelse(Att_ > dt$Max, 
                  0, 1 - pbeta(Att_ / dt$Max, dt$Alpha, dt$Beta)))))) 
    } else {
        retval <- dt[Mean > Att_, 1 - exp(-1 * sum(Rate))]
    }
    return(retval) 
}
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, but it looks like `Indemn_Bool` might be vectorizable.

Comment: I made a start at editing but yes see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems you haven't read the documentation or browsed many of the questions in this tag.